# Unexpected Duplicate Results Returned from Statement - Unsure what is missing

Tags: sql

I have a query where I am investigating what wholesale price list (PRRF) was obtained and used to provide sales prices on orders and against this I want to see what the retail price is from the retail price list (PK01). I want to return the retail price list (PK01) only where it is like the wholesale price list (First letter of wholesale and retail price lists should be the same and can either start with M or S.

what i was expecting to be returned for the example on order 1110003408 was this;

```
1001247 1110003408  SS21    USD S03 WHOLESALE   S04 RETAIL
```

what was returned for the example on order 1110003408 was this;

```
1001247 1110003408  SS21    USD S03 WHOLESALE   M04 RETAIL
1001247 1110003408  SS21    USD S03 WHOLESALE   S04 RETAIL
```

This is my query;

```
select distinct
t1.cuno as Customer,
t1.orno as OrderNumber,
t1.proj as Season,
odhead.cucd as Currency,
t1.prrf as WhslPriceList,
t2.a030 as WhslPriceListName,
t3.pk01 as RtlPriceList,
t3.a030 as RtlPriceListName
from odhead
left join ooline t1 on t1.cono = odhead.cono
    and t1.cuno = odhead.cuno
    and t1.orno = odhead.orno
left join cugex1 t2 on t2.cono = odhead.cono
    and t2.pk01 = t1.prrf
    and t2.pk02 = odhead.cucd
left join cugex1 t3 on t3.cono = odhead.cono
    and t3.pk01 LIKE '[M,S]%'
    and t3.a130 = t1.proj
    and t3.pk02 = odhead.cucd 
    and t3.a030 <> 'WHOLESALE'
where t1.orno = '1110003408'
```

Comment: Your 2 rows being returned are different for one of the values (M04 and S04)  those are not the same so you will get them (non distinct).  You can remove that column and should come back with 1 row only as rest of the data looks identical.

Comment: You mean you want to get `M04` if and only if there's no `S04`? If so, you might *group* by all other columns and select `MAX(t3.pk01)` for that specific one.

Comment: @Aconcagua No. If wholesale price list is M03 on the customer order,  i want to get the retail price list from the price list table where they are similar (both must start with the same letter, have the same currency (CUCD), and from the extension table CUGEX1 (have the same season (A130) and the same currency (CUCD) and (A030) is not 'WHOLESALE'

Comment: Have you tried `AND SUBSTRING(t3.pk01, 1, 1) = SUBSTRING(t2.pk01, 1, 1)`?

Comment: Having to deal with strings so heavily hints to your design violating NF1 already. Maybe you should think about a redesign, having 'M' and 'S' separated from the numbers, which would allow you for simple comparison for equality again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I duplicate came about based on the tables i was using and a mismatch between data between two tables that should have matched.  Example.  Sales price should have been the same on the order header and order lines however it was not and because of this I was getting duplicate records.  Database was cleaned to have accurate data and when the report was run again it worked and the report was approved and pushed into production.